# Change a button value via Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, checkbox

Sorry but I'm quite a noob if it comes to Javascript with HTML.
I'm trying to make a button that will change the value of it when a multiple checkboxes are checked.

Example: 
If one checkbox is checked    = Button: Delete 1 row
If two checkboxes are checked = Button: Delete 2 rows
etc.

And I want this to happen automaticly when I check all checkboxes. The only problem is that it won't change anything.

JS:

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click( function() {
   $("input[type=submit]").val("Delete "+$('input:checkbox:checked').length+" rows"); 
});
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success"  value="Verwijder" />
```

The server-side of this(PHP) does work(deleting the rows).
Thank you for helping and your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must put your code inside this block:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // your code
});
```

We use this because:

> The document.ready handler is triggered when the DOM has been loaded
>   by the browser and ready to be manipulated.

Second:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn js-button btn-success"  value="Verwijder" />

$(".js-button").val("Value that you need");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hzp63/3/)

**HTML**

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success"  value="Verwijder" />
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
```

**JS Code**

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(){
   var rows = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length,
       value = rows < 1 ? 'Verwijder' : 'Delete '+rows+(rows<2 ? ' row':' rows');
   $('.btn').attr('value', value);
});
```

Comment: Improved the answer...if nothing selected default value will assign to button